# php database class

Tags: php, mysql, database, class

i have created database class in php but i can't understand why it has an error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\Engine\Class\user.php on line 9
```

here is a code

```
<?php
    class user{
        private  $db_host = 'localhost';
        private $db_user = 'root';
        private $db_password = '123456';
        private $db_name = 'test';

        private function _dbconnect(){
            mysql_connect($this->db_host,  $this->db_user,  $this->db_password) or die('Unable to connect to Database'); // line 9 (error is here)
            @mysql_select_db($this->db_name) or die( "Unable to select database");
        }

        public function login(){
            self::_dbconnect();
            mysql_close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**you are all wrong** here is a sollution:

$user = new user();

```
    <?php
        class user{
            private  $db_host = 'localhost';
            private $db_user = 'root';
            private $db_password = '123456';
            private $db_name = 'test';

            private function _dbconnect(){
//***********************************************
                $user = new user();
//***********************************************
                mysql_connect($this->db_host,  $this->db_user,  $this->db_password) or die('Unable to connect to Database'); // line 9 (error is here)
                @mysql_select_db($this->db_name) or die( "Unable to select database");
            }

            public function login(){
                self::_dbconnect();
                mysql_close();
            }
        }
    ?>
```

now everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

In your function login you have to do

```
$this->_dbconnect()
```

in stead of

```
self::_dbconnect()
```

Bye doing it that way, you are calling the method statically, and thus, using `$this` in the `_dbconnect` method does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method statically

```
self::_dbconnect();
```

A static context has no object and therefore `$this` is undefined.

```
$this->dbconnect();
```

Comment: you are all wrong or php5 is another language, when i have changed self::_dbconnect() to $this->dbconnect() error another error appeared :Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\Engine\Class\user.php on line 14 (this is the line $this->dbconnect())

i have changed private function to private static function but it hasn't solved the problem. and when i use self::_dbconnect() it shows no error to that line, but it shows error to the line

    mysql_connect($this->db_host,  $this->db_user,  $this->db_password) or die('Unable to connect to Database');

Answer (score -1):

first _dbconnect is not a static function and you are calling it as a static function

change self::_dbconnect(); to $this->_dbconnect();